# How can I refactor this ruby code more?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm trying to reactor this code. Any advice?

```
@contest_users = [] 
@contest.squads.each do |squad|
  @contest_users << squad.users[0]
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `each`:

```
@contest_users = @contest.squads.map { |squad| squad.users.first }
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Your code will return first `user` of the first `squad`, but here we need an array of first `user`s in every `squad`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@contest_users = @contest.squads.each_with_object([]) do |squad, array|
  array << squad.users[0]
end
```